# Find values of x so that the matrix is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
5 &  6 &  6-x & 8 \\
2 &  2-x &  2 &  8 \\
6 &  6 &   2 &  8 \\
2 &  3 &   6 &  7
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$$

One must find all values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the matrix is not invertible.
I tried finding the determinant of $A$ and in the process got that $x = 4$ and $x = 6/192$. Therefore, $A1 = 1360; A2 = 816; A3 = 1146; A4 = 1088$. However when I calculate $\det(A) = 1360 - 816 + 1146 - 1088= 602$ and I do not get 0 so that I could prove it is not invertible.

Comment: I apologize I could not format the matrix.

Comment: Isn't there a typo somewhere / are you sure you copied the matrix correctly? According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%5B%5B5,6,6-x,8%5D,%5B2,2-x,2,8%5D,%5B6,6,2,8%5D,%5B2,3,6,7%5D%5D) the value $x=4$ is not a root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let's calculate $\det A$ as a **function of x** and then set $\det A=0$.

Note that adding a scalar multiple of one column/row to another column/row **does not change the value of the determinant**. Thus you can simplify the matrix A before to perform the calculation.

You should obtain:

$$\det A=2(-13 x^2 + 19 x - 4)$$

and from here find the values for which $\det A=0$.

Notably

$$\det A=\begin{vmatrix}
5 &  6 &  6-x & 8 \\
2 &  2-x &  2 &  8 \\
6 &  6 &   2 &  8 \\
2 &  3 &   6 &  7
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 &  x &  6-x & 8 \\
x &  -x &  2 &  8 \\
0 &  4 &   2 &  8 \\
-1 &  -3 &   6 &  7
\end{vmatrix}=\\=-1\begin{vmatrix}
  -x &  2 &  8 \\
  4 &   2 &  8 \\
  -3 &   6 &  7
\end{vmatrix}-x\begin{vmatrix}
 x &  6-x & 8 \\
 4 &   2 &  8 \\
-3 &   6 &  7
\end{vmatrix}+1\begin{vmatrix}
  x &  6-x & 8 \\
 -x &  2 &  8 \\
 4 &   2 &  8 \\
\end{vmatrix}=\\=
-1\cdot(34x+136)-x\cdot(18x-72)+(128-8x^2)=-26x^2+38x-8 $$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. What do you mean by "simplify the matrix" ?

Comment: You can subtract one column from another in order to simplify the calculation of detA. EG C1-C2, C2-C3.

Comment: After doing some row operations in order to simplify further the matrix I got: 
det(A) = 2 (-13xˆ2 - 46x - 66)  ->  not small roots

Comment: @user507945 I'm going to add some detail

Comment: Much appreciated @gimusi

Comment: I've update, anyway I suggest, for others OP, that you try to yourself to complete the answer once you have all the necessary hints and elements,otherwise it will be not so much useful to learn read the complete answer from others users.

Comment: How did you get x at position 2.1 ?

Comment: Were you working only with column operations as I see that the last two columns remain intact ?

Comment: Yes I’ve just simplyfied the first 2 columns especially in order to have a zero entry in the first and use Laplace’s expansion on it.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. However, instead of 
- x. (18x-72) 
I have -x (86x-72)

Comment: @user507945 I've checked the calculation and I conferm the previous result.

Comment: You are right, it is 18x. I was missing a minus and instead of subtracting I was adding the two numbers.

Comment: The roots are not very nice but as a result I just indicate them in the solution and say that these are the roots when det(A) = 0, right ?

Comment: @user507945 Yes it seems there are two ugly value for x such that detA=0.

Answer (score 0):

Some properties of square matrices that may be useful in your case:

If two rows/columns of a matrix are proportional the matrix is $0$. For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a &  b &  c & d \\
e &  f &  g & h \\
x &  y &  z & w \\
ka & kb & kc & kd
\end{pmatrix}=0$$ 
You can multiply any row/column of a matrix with a constant and add it to another row/column. For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a &  b &  c & d \\
e &  f &  g & h \\
x &  y &  z & w \\
i & j & m & n
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a &  b &  c & d+kb \\
e &  f &  g & h+kf \\
x &  y &  z & w+ky \\
i & j & m & n+kj
\end{pmatrix} $$ 
If any row/column of a matrix is all $0$, then the matrix is $0$. For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a &  b &  c & d \\
e &  f &  g & h \\
0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
i & j & m & n
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

By using the second property multiple times on multiple rows and columns you can get one of the rows/columns to be $0$ or be proportional and then you get that $detA=0$.

Comment: @lhf of course...fixed it